# Python: Compare two dictionaries with the same keys, identify the keys with 0 as value if the other dictionary value is more than 0

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two Dictionaries with the same keys but the values are different intergers. They both look like:

```
Dict 1        Dict2
SEQ|1|,0      SEQ|1|,4
SEQ|2|,9      SEQ|2|,7
```

I need to identify those keys values which are 0 if the same key value in another Dict has an int higher than 1 (Or not 0).

So in this case I would like to report

```
SEQ|1|,0 from Dict1
```

Thanks.

Note: The dicts have exactly the same Keys.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Uh, those don't look like `dict`s to me.

Comment: 1. I do not see the problem with my question, I would like to know how to extract those keys from a particular dictionary which is 0 when the same key and value is more than 0 in another dictionary?
2. I know it does not look like a dict but I thought it would be easier to write and read as csv rather than 'the correct' syntax.

Comment: It is sad to see Stackoverflow turn into a little princesses corner.. 
I have clearly stated what I need but rather than help it seems many in the community would rather nit pick.. Wow..

Comment: It is unclear because, here, in this particular case, you could ask for a function that takes 2 dict as inputs + a third parameter which would be the key you want to check, and the function would return 0 or 1 depending on your condition. **Or**, it could be a function that compares the 2 exact dict with different values and return a list of booleans that tells us which keys are what according to your condition. **Or** anything else I haven't thought of.

Comment: No, it isn't easier to read as a csv. The problem is that it is ambiguous. Python, as a programming language, gives you an entirely *unambiguous* way to write `dict` objects, with the added benefit that we can *run it as code*. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Unfortunately the Dicts I am working with look like: 'SEQ|100000014|,101850538_1':4 etc. And I believed I was asking more of a theoretical question, rather than a code example. Usually there is a known method of this type of dictionary manipulation and extraction. If we have to go straight to downvote and therefore remove the chances of getting help then that just has the be the way it is unfortunately..

I have seen and asked many questions which simply ask for a theoretical response and they do not get shot down like this.. Seems to be a more recent change,

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
for key in dict1:
    if (dict1[key] == 0) != (dict2[key] == 0):
        print(key)
```

this will only work if both have exactly the same keys

Comment: It really was that simple.. Now I see why even if I had written my question correctly, it was still simple.. Thank you. - The Keys are the KEY!

Answer (score 1):

A Little Princess suggests you this one-liner style code that retrieves the desired keys in a list:

```
ListResult = [a for (a,b) in Dict1.items() if ((b == 0) and Dict2[a] > 0)]
```